# Tomcat recreate JSESSIONID cookie after client redirect

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, jsessionid

I am stuck with a jsession id problem. I am using Tomcat 7, Spring framework 3.1.1, security with Spring Security.

Our application has a login page with an url like : `defaultSubdomain.theSite.com/login.html`. Some of our users have their own subdomains, so their login page url are : `subdomainForUser.theSite.com/login.html`.

The problem is, if one of them use the default login url :

- he will be log in, an HttpSession will be created on the server and a JSESSIONID cookie will be created on `defaultSubdomain.theSite.com` on client, then
- our server makes the browser redirect to the welcome page of user's subdomain and makes the browser recreate the JSESSIONID cookie with javascript.

In a filter:

```
//if client is on the wrong subdomain
HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(url);
return;
```

But after that, client still needs to log in again. Is there any way to achieve what I try to do (with a coding approach and not configuring tomcat)?

I made some research and we could use

```
<Context sessionCookieDomain=".theSite.com" sessionCookiePath="/">
```

but it implies having one configuration for dev, one for test and one for prod which is not acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe redirect the user to his subdomain and include the session ID in the URL, like `http://subdomainForUser.theSite.com/;jsessionid=A463B23BC4F2342FA`?

Comment: Please give more information. What is the Tomcat application doing? Do you use a HttpSession object? Maybe you can just set this created JSESSIONID in header: "HttpSession session = request.getSession(); response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getId()+ ";Path=/; HttpOnly");"

Comment: This has been done:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82645/best-way-for-allowing-subdomain-session-cookies-using-tomcat

Comment: @NickJ Thanks for the link but like I was saying at the end of my question, I would like to avoid configuring tomcat.

Comment: @mthmulders I tried your suggestion but it doesn't use the session ID to recreate the cookie on client side.

Comment: The `<Context...` configuration option might work if you just instruct people to have `theSite.com` in their hosts file pointing to `127.0.0.1`. For test, you could have it point to the IP address of your test environment, etc. But it's a bit of a work-around.

Comment: @mthmulders I will try it if I have no other possibilities. 
I did not ask, what "/;jsessionid=A463B23BC4F2342FA" means and what will do the browser with that?
Thanks!

Comment: See section 7.1.3 on URL Rewriting of the [JSR-000315 Java Servlet 3.0 Final Release](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html). In short: "URL rewriting involves adding data, a session ID, to the URL path  that is interpreted by the container to associate the request with a session.  The session ID must be encoded as a path parameter in the URL string."

Comment: Same configuration for dev/test/prod? Sounds like a tight ship. *eyeroll*

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no there is not one configuration but I prefer adding 1 line of code than 3 for configuration. More efficient, no?

Comment: @sk2212 thanks for your advice! I replaced the REFRESH header by a simpler HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect and added the SET-COOKIE header, now it works fine.

Comment: @mthmuldersand Should I provide my comment as an answer for better traceability?