# Spring-Security : Ignoring alias of server-name and forcing relogin

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a project in which I use Spring-Security for authentication and authorization. Everything seems to be working fine, just that Spring-security is ignoring `Alias-name` of the server.
So, for example, if I login with `domain-name.com` and visit some secured resource, I have no problem. But now when someone gives me a link like `www-domain-name.com/secured/resource`, then I am forced to login once again, and then it works fine.

How can I ensure that when I login, I login into both `domain-name.com` and `www.domain-name.com`. What is this problem called as?

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/dashboard"
                             always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/denied"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
            <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>-->
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>

        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionReg" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

If anything more is required, kindly let me know. Thank you.

*Update*
I added this in both Tomcat instance in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` :

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/" sessionCookieDomain=".domainname.com" />
```

That's killing the server, the webapp wont load. Nothing in logs I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its not spring-security problem, but its servlet problem. You can try subdomain cookie sharing for tomcat:

```
<Context sessionCookieDomain=".domain-name.com" />
```

using spring-boot:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
        {
            servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setDomain(".domain-name.com");
        }
    };

}
```

Ref: [Best way for allowing subdomain session cookies using Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82645/best-way-for-allowing-subdomain-session-cookies-using-tomcat)

Comment: In the reference you gave me, there is also sessionCookieDomain, what should I add in there, JSESSIONID?

Comment: your domain name with initial dot e.g.: .example.com

Comment: And I was making a mistake to create a new Context and add it in that, but that killed the server. When I added the parameters in existing context, it didn't work, but didn't kill my server as well. I hope you understood, what am I doing wrong?