# Use sessionCookieDomain in META-INF/context.xml only when deployed to production

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, spring-security, session-cookies, context.xml

I have an Enterprise Java application with Spring Security on AWS, configured to use `myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com`. The problem is that both of these maintain a separate session *(requiring login on one even if you're logged in on the other)*, which I want to solve.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427285/3906773) mentions that you can achieve this by setting `sessionCookieDomain` in `META-INF/context.xml` to the root domain -

`<Context sessionCookiePath="/" sessionCookieDomain=".myapp.com" />`

However, this does not allow me to run the web app locally. I have to either remove or replace it with -

`<Context sessionCookiePath="/myapp" sessionCookieDomain="localhost" />`

I'm fine with not having to specify it for running it locally. So, is there a way to use that `<Context>` parameter only when the web application is deployed to production?

If not, is it possible to either dynamically modify them based on the environment *(local or production)*, or specify them both without conflict? Currently, Eclipse won't allow me to specify both.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to map the "local.myapp.com" domain to your local IP?
And you may use the same `sessionCookieDomain=".myapp.com"` configurations.

And I just tried that `sessionCookieDomain="myapp.com"` seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of configuration is specific to the server, where the application is deployed, so it shouldn't be distributed in `META-INF/context.xml`. A more proper location would be:

- a `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default`, where `[enginename]` is usually `Catalina`, while `[hostname]` is the configured name of the `<Host>`,
- or `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` if this concerns all `<Host>` elements.

#### See also:

- [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)